# MongoDB's new and upsert

Tags: mongodb

I recently started to learn about MongoDB.
Today I read that I can create sequence by using the following code;

```
function seq_no(name) { 
    var ret = db.seq_no.findAndModify ({query:{_id:name}, update:{$inc:{next:1}}, "new":true, upsert:true}); 
    return ret.next; 
}

db.order_no.insert({_id:seq_no("order_no"), name:"Jimmy"})
```

I'm wondering what the difference is between "new" and upsert here.
would you explain?

Comment: Read the documentation of [`.findOneAndUpdate()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/) maybe? Since that is the method that is actually not deprecated.

Answer (score 4):

They are completely different flags

If **upsert** is true then if the row trying to be updated does not exist then a new row is inserted instead , if false then it does not do anything .

If **new** is true then the modified document is returned after the update rather than the original , if false then the original document is returned